# How to modify a 'struct msghdr' in Linux Kernel Module?

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to implement a new transport layer protocol above UDP in Linux. To send a datagram, I registered my `rudp_sendmsg` like this:

```
int rudp_sendmsg(struct sock *sk, struct msghdr *msg, size_t len)
{
    struct RUDP_header hdr = {
        .seq = 12345,
        .ack = 23456,
        .len = len,
    };
    int hlen = sizeof(hdr);
    void *ubuf = msg->msg_iter.ubuf;
    memcpy(ubuf+hlen,ubuf,len);
    memcpy(ubuf,&hdr,len);
    return udp_prot.sendmsg(sk,msg,len+hlen);
}
```

Before sending a datagram through UDP, I want to insert a my `RUDP_header` in front of msg(the app data), but i does'nt work, this is what the  `dmesg` command shows:

```
[  235.256131] BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: 00007ffd0047db50
[  235.256140] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
[  235.256142] #PF: error_code(0x0001) - permissions violation
[  235.256144] PGD 1156e5067 P4D 1156e5067 PUD 1088c1067 PMD 108725067 PTE 800000012d61c867
[  235.256151] Oops: 0001 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
[  235.256155] CPU: 2 PID: 4678 Comm: client Tainted: G           OE      6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[  235.256159] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 11/12/2020
[  235.256161] RIP: 0010:memcpy_orig+0x8c/0x130
[  235.256167] Code: 5e e0 48 8d 76 e0 4c 89 47 f8 4c 89 4f f0 4c 89 57 e8 4c 89 5f e0 48 8d 7f e0 73 d2 83 c2 20 48 29 d6 48 29 d7 83 fa 10 72 34 <4c> 8b 06 4c 8b 4e 08 4c 8b 54 16 f0 4c 8b 5c 16 f8 4c 89 07 4c 89
[  235.256170] RSP: 0018:ffffb42403a7bce0 EFLAGS: 00010202
[  235.256173] RAX: 00007ffd0047db5e RBX: 000000000000001b RCX: 0000000000000000
[  235.256175] RDX: 000000000000001b RSI: 00007ffd0047db50 RDI: 00007ffd0047db5e
[  235.256177] RBP: ffffb42403a7bd20 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  235.256179] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffb42403a7bd78
[  235.256182] R13: ffff8ee008c12d00 R14: 00007ffd0047db50 R15: ffffb42403a7bde0
[  235.256184] FS:  00007f03baab03c0(0000) GS:ffff8ee039e80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  235.256187] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  235.256189] CR2: 00007ffd0047db50 CR3: 000000010345e000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
[  235.256207] Call Trace:
[  235.256210]  <TASK>
[  235.256215]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[  235.256222]  ? __die+0x24/0x80
[  235.256226]  ? page_fault_oops+0x99/0x1b0
[  235.256231]  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x31d/0x6b0
[  235.256233]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[  235.256238]  ? sock_i_uid+0x3a/0x50
[  235.256243]  ? exc_page_fault+0x83/0x1b0
[  235.256248]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
[  235.256256]  ? memcpy_orig+0x8c/0x130
[  235.256262]  ? rudp_sendmsg+0x5a/0xc0 [RUDP_mod]
[  235.256269]  inet_sendmsg+0x7d/0x80
[  235.256274]  __sys_sendto+0x220/0x250
[  235.256297]  __x64_sys_sendto+0x24/0x40
[  235.256300]  do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x90
[  235.256304]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[  235.256307]  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x238/0x6b0
[  235.256310]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[  235.256313]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x30/0xb0
[  235.256317]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[  235.256320]  ? irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x17/0x20
[  235.256323]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[  235.256327]  ? irqentry_exit+0x43/0x50
[  235.256330]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
[  235.256333]  ? exc_page_fault+0x94/0x1b0
[  235.256337]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0xd8
[  235.256341] RIP: 0033:0x7f03ba527a0a
[  235.256359] Code: d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb b8 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 41 89 ca 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 15 b8 2c 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 7e c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 41 54 48 83 ec 30 44 89
[  235.256361] RSP: 002b:00007ffd0047db28 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002c
[  235.256364] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007f03ba527a0a
[  235.256367] RDX: 000000000000001b RSI: 00007ffd0047db50 RDI: 0000000000000003
[  235.256369] RBP: 00007ffd0047dbc0 R08: 00007ffd0047db40 R09: 0000000000000010
[  235.256371] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007ffd0047dcd8
[  235.256373] R13: 000064cb39e0e32e R14: 000064cb39e10d50 R15: 00007f03bab1b040
[  235.256378]  </TASK>
[  235.256380] Modules linked in: RUDP_mod(OE) isofs bnep snd_ens1371 snd_ac97_codec intel_rapl_msr gameport ac97_bus snd_pcm intel_rapl_common vsock_loopback vmw_vsock_virtio_transport_common vmw_balloon vmw_vsock_vmci_transport crct10dif_pclmul polyval_clmulni snd_seq_midi polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel sha256_ssse3 vsock snd_seq_midi_event sha1_ssse3 aesni_intel snd_rawmidi crypto_simd cryptd binfmt_misc snd_seq btusb btrtl nls_iso8859_1 joydev snd_seq_device btbcm btintel input_leds btmtk snd_timer serio_raw bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc snd soundcore vmw_vmci mac_hid sch_fq_codel vmwgfx drm_ttm_helper ttm drm_kms_helper msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic crc32_pclmul psmouse mptspi usbhid hid ahci mptscsih mptbase e1000 scsi_transport_spi libahci i2c_piix4 pata_acpi
[  235.256467] CR2: 00007ffd0047db50
[  235.256470] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[  235.256472] RIP: 0010:memcpy_orig+0x8c/0x130
[  235.256475] Code: 5e e0 48 8d 76 e0 4c 89 47 f8 4c 89 4f f0 4c 89 57 e8 4c 89 5f e0 48 8d 7f e0 73 d2 83 c2 20 48 29 d6 48 29 d7 83 fa 10 72 34 <4c> 8b 06 4c 8b 4e 08 4c 8b 54 16 f0 4c 8b 5c 16 f8 4c 89 07 4c 89
[  235.256478] RSP: 0018:ffffb42403a7bce0 EFLAGS: 00010202
[  235.256480] RAX: 00007ffd0047db5e RBX: 000000000000001b RCX: 0000000000000000
[  235.256482] RDX: 000000000000001b RSI: 00007ffd0047db50 RDI: 00007ffd0047db5e
[  235.256484] RBP: ffffb42403a7bd20 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  235.256486] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffb42403a7bd78
[  235.256488] R13: ffff8ee008c12d00 R14: 00007ffd0047db50 R15: ffffb42403a7bde0
[  235.256491] FS:  00007f03baab03c0(0000) GS:ffff8ee039e80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  235.256493] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  235.256495] CR2: 00007ffd0047db50 CR3: 000000010345e000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
[  235.256505] note: client[4678] exited with irqs disabled
```

It seems like `struct msghdr` has to be read and write by `copy_to_iter` and `copy_from_iter`, but I can only read from msg, I can't write to msg. The Linux Kernel version is 6.5.0, so the 'struct msghdr' is different from old version, it has no `iovec`, but `iov_iter`.
Does anybody know how to solve this, I need help, thanks a lot!

I tried `memcpy`, `copy_to_iter`, `iov_iter_init` and `copy_to_user`, but none of them works. May be I didn't use them correctly. `copy_to_iter` and `copy_to_user` always return `0`, but I don't know why.

Comment: Without much detail knowledge about kernel details, I see 2 issues: a) `memcpy(ubuf+hlen,ubuf,len);` Using `memcpy` to copy between memory areas that overlap is causing undefined behaviour. You would need `memmov` for this. b) What makes you assume, that the memory where `ubuf` points to, can hold the extra `len` bytes?

Comment: @Gerhardh It doesn't seem to be the point, every time I try to read/write ubuf pointer, the kernel module crashes. I think there is a better way to get access to the msghdr, but I don't know how.

Comment: @zhf999 I think you don't get what Gerhardh has told you. Your code is using memory that does not belong to your application. This is what the kernel tells you with the page fault (Writing to a copy-on-write page). Your application needs to create a new buffer of the same size as the header and payload data, copy the data there, and then send the data using the new buffer.

Comment: @Risto But msg->msg_iter must point to a user space, how can I get a user space address in Linux kernel Module?

Comment: @zhf999 here you find all you need to know: https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/